# Returning a null value to C#/XAML DatePicker through a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing a Converter for my DatePicker, which is bound to a field within a table.  Everything appears to be working fine, except that if the user wipes the date.  It then displays (and potentially stores) the date as 01/01/0001, where as I really do need it to be a blank/null value.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
try
{
    DateTime dt;
    string strValue = value.ToString();

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strValue, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is your `strValue` exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, DateTime is a Struct i.e. a value type which cannot be null.

However you can do inside if statement after you parse it

```
if (dt == DateTime.MinValue)
    return String.Empty;
else
    return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is a value type and cannot be null.

If you want "null" DateTime values, then simply use a nullable DateTime.

```
DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Nullable datetime by doing this:

```
public DateTime? YourDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely common problem and has a number of potential solutions. The first is to use the nullable `DateTime` struct:

```
DateTime? nullableDateTime = null;
```

Another solution is just to edit the date value before it goes to the database and once it comes out of the database:

Into the database:

```
if (yourDateValue == DateTime.MinValue) databaseTable.Date = null;
else databaseTable.Date = yourDateValue;
```

Out of the database:

```
if (databaseTable.Date == null) yourDateValue = DateTime.MinValue;
else yourDateValue = databaseTable.Date;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone - that's a big help.